# Adding integration response to AWS websocket API with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

AWS [recently released Cloudformation support for templating websocket API gateways](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/02/automate-websocket-api-creation-in-api-gateway-with-cloudformation/). I have a working example deployed, but I can't work out how to turn on the proxy integration response (see screenshot for how this is done in the console). Does anyone know what cloudFormation setting can be used to turn on a default integration response for lambda proxy integrations?
[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please try below steps

1- Add RouteResponseSelectionExpression in Route as $default(this is only one supported as of now)

2- Create RouteResponse for all routes(bidirectional)
Note:- RouteResponseKey: $default // it should be default only

3- Add ConnectIntegResponse(Optional)

Below is a tested CFN snippet, feel free to use it

```js
##########Socket API###############
  webSocket:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: WebSocket
      ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
      RouteSelectionExpression: "$request.body.action"
  ConnectRoute:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
      RouteKey: $connect
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      OperationName: ConnectRoute
      RouteResponseSelectionExpression: $default # add this 
      Target: !Join
        - '/'
        - - 'integrations'
          - !Ref ConnectInteg
  ConnectInteg:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
      Description: Connect Integration
      IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
      IntegrationUri: 
        Fn::Sub:
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${restAndSocketLambda.Arn}/invocations

  ConnectRouteResponse: # Add this
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::RouteResponse'
    Properties:
      RouteId: !Ref ConnectRoute
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
      RouteResponseKey: $default

  ConnectIntegResponse: # Add this(if required)
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::IntegrationResponse'
    Properties:
      IntegrationId: !Ref ConnectInteg
      IntegrationResponseKey: /201/
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
```

Comment: Thank you times 1000 for this answer. I was stuck without knowing about "RouteResponseSelectionExpression" all day today.

Comment: I can see responses when adding this to a `sendmessage` route, but when adding it to the `$connect` I don't see any response coming back to websocket client.
Also the IntegrationResponse does not seem required, at least for HTTP_PROXY integration type