# Adding integration response to AWS websocket API with @aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Is there a way to add an integration response to the AWS WebSocket API using AWS CDK with the aws-apigatewayv2 package? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643795/adding-integration-response-to-aws-websocket-api-with-cloudformation) shows a great way to achieve just that using CloudFormation. But I haven't been able to translate it into the AWS CDK. Thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have clarified how I am trying to add the integration response now:

```
  const webSocketApi = new WebSocketApi(this, 'Api', {
    defaultRouteOptions: {
      integration: new LambdaWebSocketIntegration({ handler: lambdaFn }),
    },
  })
  new CfnIntegrationResponse(this, 'response', {
    apiId: webSocketApi.apiId,
    integrationId: /* ? */,
    integrationResponseKey: '$default',
  })
  const stage = new WebSocketStage(this, 'Stage', {
    webSocketApi,
    stageName: 'dev',
    autoDeploy: true,
  })
```

I could add the integration response using CfnIntegrationResponse but I don't have a way to access the integration id of the LambdaWebSocketIntegration.

Comment: Stack Overflow would like you to try a few things first - so what have you tried? If you look at the CDK documenation for apigatewayv2 you can see that Websockets are there but experimental (meaning they could change in any deployment). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-readme.html

what have you tried out of it?

Comment: I don't think AWS CDK supports integration response yet. Take a look at the official documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-readme.html#websocket-api

Comment: Anything you can do with CloudFormation you can do with aws-cdk.

Comment: I appreciate everyone looking into this. @lynkfox - I've updated the question.

Comment: @noninertialframe - They seem to support the v1 API via CfnIntegrationResponse but I can't figure out how to make it work together with v2

Comment: looks like you will have to use one of the escape hatchs - there are many functions in the core module of cdk that are representitve of cloudformation tags - they allow you to 'write' your own cloud formation snippet in cdk. Take a look through how to use the Escape Hatches for cfn to achieve what the higher level CDK constructs are not yet hooked up to do https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html

Comment: @lynkfox - So far it looks like it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `CfnRouteResponse` instead of `CfnIntegrationResponse`, like this:

```
const api = new WebSocketApi(...)
const route = api.addRoute(...)

new apigateway.CfnRouteResponse(this, "wsRouteResponse", {
    apiId: api.apiId,
    routeId: route.routeId,
    routeResponseKey: "$default",
});
```

Comment: This works, but do you know how to add to the defaultRoute? My API is configured here:

`const webSocketApi = new WebSocketApi(this, 'FraudWebsocketApi', {
      connectRouteOptions: { integration: new WebSocketLambdaIntegration('ConnectIntegration', connectFunction) },
      defaultRouteOptions: { integration: new WebSocketLambdaIntegration('DefaultIntegration', connectFunction) }
    });`

Comment: @LeeHannigan Have you tried removing `defaultRouteOptions` from the api params and manually declare the default route using `const defaultRoute = webSocketApi.addRoute('$default', {integration: new WebSocketLambdaIntegration('DefaultIntegration', connectFunction)})`?

If this works you could access `defaultRoute.routeId` and create a `CfnRouteReponse` for it.

Comment: The last comment is the correct "answer"!!! @yeahwhat please add this as an answer, this should be the accepted one add the end :)

Answer (score 0):

There's still no way to rewrite this [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) example in [cdk](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/).

```
##########Socket API###############
  webSocket:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: WebSocket
      ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
      RouteSelectionExpression: "$request.body.action"
  ConnectRoute:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
      RouteKey: $connect
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      OperationName: ConnectRoute
      RouteResponseSelectionExpression: $default # add this 
      Target: !Join
        - '/'
        - - 'integrations'
          - !Ref ConnectInteg
  ConnectInteg:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
      Description: Connect Integration
      IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
      IntegrationUri: 
        Fn::Sub:
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${restAndSocketLambda.Arn}/invocations

  ConnectRouteResponse: # Add this
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::RouteResponse'
    Properties:
      RouteId: !Ref ConnectRoute
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
      RouteResponseKey: $default

  ConnectIntegResponse: # Add this(if required)
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::IntegrationResponse'
    Properties:
      IntegrationId: !Ref ConnectInteg
      IntegrationResponseKey: /201/
      ApiId: !Ref webSocket
```

I tried using [escape hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html), but I did not manage to add valid resources references to the synthesized Cloudformation template.

I suggest to include the entire template fragment in a stack using the [CfnInclude](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.cloudformation_include-readme.html) construct.

```
new CfnInclude(this, 'ID', {
  template: {
    Resources: {
      Bucket: {
        Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket',
        Properties: {
          BucketName: 'my-shiny-bucket'
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).